# Display dynamic audio file name

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio

I have this fairly simple script that displays a html5 audio player. The player play's a file and when it's done, it plays a different file. It plays a different file because the php file redirects to a different mp3 every time. Is there a way to display the filename of the file currently being played in the player? or to check if it is playing a certain file?

The Jquery

```
  $(document).ready(function(){


      $("#player").bind("ended", function(){
         this.src = "song.php?nocache="+new Date().getTime();
             this.play();       
      });


    });
```

And the html

```
<audio id="player" autoplay="autoplay">
  <source src="song.php" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: You want to display the song name to the person visiting the website?

Comment: Yes. I want to be able to know which file is playing.

Comment: In `bind("ended")` function, send a request to php file to get the filename first, then play the file

Comment: If you want to display it on the website you can add a label, I am not sure how you want it to look... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401034/create-a-label-using-jquery-on-the-fly

Comment: I don't really care how it looks. But I am having trouble doing this as it will displays. "song.php" instead of the file it's actually playing.